# Add model atribute to result of a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models and they look like (simplified):

```
class Airline < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :airplanes
  has_many :airplane_switches
end

class Airplane < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :airline_id, :register
  belongs_to :airline
  has_many :airplane_switches
end

class AirplaneSwitch < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :airline_id, :airplane_id
  belongs_to :airplane
  belongs_to :airline
end
```

**Airplanes** could have been in some **Airlines**, so I needed another model that indicates if an **Airplane** was in one or more **Airlines**.

I am building a form to let users upload some info about an **Airplane**, they just select the airplane register (callsign) and then they will get a list to choose in which **Airline** it was.

This will work over an AJAX request. But, I am trying to figure out how to show the **Airline** name from my controller, to avoid another AJAX call by fetching another JSON file just to get the name of the Airline based on the `airline_id` in **AirplaneSwitch**.

```
@airplane = Airplane.find_by_register(params[:register])
@airplane_switches = @airplane.airplane_switches # Here I need to join also each Airline.name
```

I think this way would be more efficient, but I have no idea if it's possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@airplane.airplane_switches.select('*, airlines.name as airline_name').joins(:airline)
```

Let's say you have variable `airplane_switch` that contains `AirlineSwitch` instance fetched in that way. All you need to do to get your airline name is:

```
airplane_switch.airline_name
```